# Conditional access in Raspberry Pi using MFRC522

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to make a conditional access in Raspberry Pi using MFRC522. And the code doesn't seem to work.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
import datetime

reader = SimpleMFRC522()

allowed_id = "141854387750"



try:
    while True:
        print("Hold an RFID tag near the reader")
        id = reader.read_id()
        
        if id == allowed_id:
            print("Access granted for Tag ID:", id)
            print("Data:", text)
        else:
            print("Access denied.", id)
            
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

[This is the output when I run it on the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cHDX.jpg)

I thought if I wrote the serial number correctly and predefine it, I could grant access to that specific ID. Is something wrong with my code? Or it's a hardware problem? Where or how did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing `"141854387750"` to a number, I just removed the quotation marks: `allowed_id = 141854387750`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you were guided by this, but maybe it will help you https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-rc522/

Or maybe `sudo usermod -aG gpio user`

It is also written that the label should be close enough, do you have a spare one to check?

Comment: I used that as a guide. But I solved it by changing "141854387750" to a number, I just removed the quotation marks.